# How to use ffmpeg to add 3D metadata to a SBS Full Frame video without reencoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, metadata

Ok so, I've been searching around for how to do this, but I've had no luck.

I have an SBS Full Frame 3D MP4 that is **648x720p per eye** (1296x720p "raw" resolution). I want to use ffmpeg to add metadata to it so YouTube will accept it as a 3D video, with the 3D option in the cog menu and all. **I also want to do this without re-encoding.** All of the tutorials I found either re-encode the video (bad!) or make YouTube treat it as an SBS *Half* Frame video (wrong!).

Answer with a full command. Please, no flags on their own or just saying to "look in this `.h` file for this flag and add it to the command" (I DON'T know how to do that!). Sorry, but I just want to quickly make a `.dll` for this and forget about how it works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:v stereo_mode=left_right out.mkv
```

Once you have this MKV, you can upload that or run

```
ffmpeg -i out.mkv -map 0 -c copy -strict -1 out.mp4
```

Comment: I've just tested it, and these commands are for SBS Half Frame. I know this because when I upload the file to Youtube, the output is stretched horizontally: https://youtu.be/ZEgFnvJDkyE I need SBS FULL Frame so that the YouTube video is 9:10, not 9:5.

Comment: Share log of `ffmpeg -i out.mp4`

Comment: https://hastebin.com/enopufolor.pas

Comment: I've found a list of values that `stereo_mode` can have: http://www.ffmpeg-archive.org/How-to-identify-a-video-is-3D-td3857078.html#a3859091 Maybe we can find a workaround by using some other value than `left_right`.

Comment: Do you have a sample of a full SBS video, recognized as such by YT or other players?

Comment: No, I do not. I heard in the past you could get around this by putting `yt3d:aspect=x:x` in the video tags to force an aspect ratio, but I tested it and it no longer works.

Comment: You can add `-aspect 1:2` and try.

Comment: I tried `ffmpeg -i %file%.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -aspect 9:10 -metadata:s:v stereo_mode=left_right temp.mkv` (without modifying the second command), and that just turned it into an SBS Half Frame video. If YouTube really doesn't support Full Frame SBS, then I'm fine with Half Frame. It's just the loss of quality (pixels are 2:1) that bugs me.